# How to display google map in div class not in id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```
<div id="custom-gmap-id">
```

How to display google map on div class ("custom-gmap-class") instead of id ("custom-gmap-id").

```
<div class="custom-gmap-class"></div>
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:

```
<div class="custom-gmap-class"></div>
```

document.getElement**s**ByClassName returns an array of DOM elements, use `document.getElementsByClassName("custom-gmap-class")[0]`.

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementsByClassName("custom-gmap-class")[0], {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
.custom-gmap-class {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="custom-gmap-class"></div>
```